# How to disable GWT ValueListBox?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

ValueListBox doesn't implement HasEnabled interface, so I can't disable/enable it.

And although ListBox implements HasEnabled, method getListBox is private in  ValueListBox. So I cannot get inner listBox, to disable it.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
DOM.setElementPropertyBoolean(valueListBoxObject.getElement(), "disabled", boolean)
```

Rest GWT should add a method, which isn't there for now.

Comment: Great, then mark above answer as useful as that might help others too ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
valueListBoxObject.getElement().setAttribute("disabled", "true");
```

I've tried it and it works.